# unable to push selected values of dropdown in a javascript array (meteor js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select id="select_opt" class="form-control">
    {{# each manageprofile_data}}
        <option>{{Usergroup}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

and its corresponding JS event helper in meteorjs as:

```
'change #select_opt': function(event){
    var select_data = [];
    var val = $('#select_opt option:selected').val();
    select_data.push(val);
    console.log(select_data);
}
```

I want to push each selected option in the select_data array but it is only inserting a single element all the times and not saving all the elements.

on clicking each select option the value of the selected option must be saved in the array like `["ROOT", "ADMINISTRATOR", "ROOT"...]`
but currently I am getting: `["ROOT"]`, `["ADMINISTRATION"]` on clicking each option.

Comment: A `select` can only have one value (unless you use the `multiple` attribute, which your code is not). Therefore I'm not sure why you're expecting an array with more than one value in it?

Comment: Just pass the ```multiple``` attribute to the select and you will get it's value from ```$('#select_opt').val()``` as an array of selected options.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your array outside of the function, like this:

```
var select_data = [];

'change #select_opt': function(event){       
   var val = $('#select_opt option:selected').val();
   select_data.push(val);
   console.log(select_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using backbone.js. You only have to make your `select_data` global. Inside your view add below line

```
select_data : [],
```